# how do I capture a set of groups out of a string in particular order

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to build an alternative data entry, wherein the user will express some sort of command, that i'll parse.  Rather than go into the details of the vocabulary I would be using in this effort here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish with appoligies to Rex Harrison.

given the following sentences

> the rain in spain falls on the plain
>
> in spain on the plain falls the rain
>
> on the meadow the snow falls in london

in **pseudo** regex:

```
(the (?<weather>\w+)) (in (<?city>\w+)) (falls) (on the (?<topography>\w+))
```

in short I need to harvest out of the sentence the weather, city and topography, using RegEx.

How do I express a set of captures that can occur in the input in any order?

Comment: what if the city is "San Francisco"?

Comment: @Kenny you're absolutely right, San Franciso (and the like) would be a problem, which is where my English words analogy breaks down.

In my case, these token values will be my well codes well known to the user, and I suppose we may be able to make it a constraint that the tokens are all single word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:on the (?<area>\w+)() ?|the (?<weather>\w+)() ?|in (?<location>\w+)() ?|falls() ){4}\1\2\3\4$
```

will match a sentence that contains each of the elements *exactly once in any order*. That's what the empty parentheses are for - each one has to take part in the match so the final `\1\2\3\4` can match.

The named backreferences will contain the variable elements.

Comment: +1: That's ingenious! Quick note though: some engines (e.g. Python's) will count the named captures with the numbered ones, so you might need to use `\2\4\6\7` in such a case.

Comment: That's interesting. RegexBuddy doesn't take this fact into account. In .NET, the above regex should work, though. It's probably generally a bad idea to mix named and unnamed capturing groups; I did it here to illustrate a point better.

Comment: Playing around with this some more.  I expected that I would have been able to do {1,4}\1\2\3\4  and capture at least 1, and at most 4 of the tokens, but that didn't seem to work, it's 4 or nothing.  How would I match a partial "sentence"?

Comment: The `\1\2\3\4` are used to make sure that each group participates once in the match. If you remove that bit, it should work - but then you have no protection against duplicates ("on the plain on the train"). If that is a problem, you're out of luck with regexes (which aren't really the right tool for this, as Max already noted).

Comment: @Max -- if there is a better tool for this, accessable to .NET 3.5 then I'm game to give it a try.  I picked Rexex because it's the closest I've got.

Answer (score 2):

First off, this looks like a problem that begs for a natural language parser.

But if you really want a regex solution, you'll have to pick out each pattern separately, either by using 3 regexes or by alternating them with pipes, e.g.:

```
(the (?<weather>\w+))|(in (<?city>\w+))|(on the (?<topography>\w+))
```

Running the above against any of your sample sentences, you'll get 3 matches, each of which will have one of its three groups set.